# Ordering/ Sorting product displays on the product category page

Tags: views

I have created product displays which are now showing on the relevant category pages (product-category/%). The product category page is created in views which is great but I want to have full control over the order of which the products are displayed (top to bottom).

At the moment in 'Sort Criteria' of views I only have options to sort by Title, ID, Date posted and Category which is not useful. I want to sort by something like SKU or some other field of the product.

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll probably need to add the product entity as a relationship to get access to its fields

Comment: Ok I have done this and have lots of fields to add in the 'Field' area of views but Sort Criteria still has the small list!

Comment: How about re-making your view so it shows Commerce Products, and add the relationship to the product display the other way round to get node data? That way you should definitely have SKU available as a sort option from the base table (`commerce_product`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How about re-making your view so it shows Commerce Products, and add
>   the relationship to the product display the other way round to get
>   node data? That way you should definitely have SKU available as a sort
>   option from the base table (commerce_product)
>   - Clive

Thanks Clive - this worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can add any field you want to the Sort Criteria. hit the "Add" button and pick Content: SKU (or whatever it's called).

Comment: This option is not available only "Index Node:" stuff

Answer (score 0):

In order to have full control over your products order you can install a great module [Draggable Views](https://drupal.org/project/draggableviews). Then add a integer field to your product content type.

Create yourself a new "admin view" using a draggable table (Drupal 7 is just a table) and add all the fields you need including the integer sort field.

In Drupal 6 you will have to set the sorting field in the table settings, where in Drupal 7 you add another field "Draggableviews:content"

Inside your Product view as well as in your admin set the sort field as the integer sort field that you created.

Now you are able to re-order your products much like the menu system in Drupal Core.